# PHP+Ajax: get unique string before long running script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know that this is a common question.
Long story made short: I would show progress to user during long running script.

This is my code/idea: store "progress" in mysql  so Ajax can read it (of course via PHP).

`"progress()"` is the "long" running script test:

```
public function startProgress()
{
    $this->unique = sha1(session_id().uniqid().time());
    echo json_encode($this->unique);
    $this->progress();
}

public function progress()
{
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
        $this->progress = $i;
        $this->setProgress();
        sleep(1);
    }

}

private function setProgress()
{

    $progress = array('tot'=>10,'current'=>$this->progress);

    $args['service'] = $this->unique;
    $args['progress'] = json_encode($progress);

    $progress_service = New ProgressService();
    $progress = $progress_service->getProgress($args['service']);

    if ($progress!=null)
    {
        $args['id'] = $progress[0]->id;
    }

    $progress_service->setData($args);

}
```

Basically my idea is:

1) Generate an unique string (`$this->unique = sha1(session_id().uniqid().time());`

2) Store for reference (using it in saveData) and encode in JSON and output to the javascript / jquery, so I can use it to launch another script via Ajax to search in database.

My issue is that the echo is output only after the end of progress (~ 10 seconds, with `$i<10` and `sleep(1)` )

How I could obtain "immediately" that unique?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with PHP but having done something similar in Java in the past are you sure you are not having transaction issues, ie. the progress being written in the DB in the same transaction that does your processing and therefore the progress not being available for read by another thread before the transaction completes?

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for might be [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php). Call that immediately after the `echo`. What this does is to **ATTEMPT** to send all output to the browser immediately before the script has completed. The thing to remember here is that the connection will probably stay open, so in the browser, it might return the JSON fast, but the request won't be complete.

A better option might be to fire off a request to the server to get a unique id and then fire off another request to kick off the long running process with the id that was received earlier. So first call preps, 2nd executes.